# Can I get my Super Advantage Controller (SNES controller) to work for more games?

Tags: drivers, usb, wine, games, joystick

Right now my controller only works for Spelunky Classic (via wine) and I'm trying to get it to work for Spelunky HD aka. Spelunky World. lsusb lists it as

```
   Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0e8f:3013 GreenAsia Inc.
```

and according to evtest it's at

```
   /dev/input/event2
```

Relevent output of evtest:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
 Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xe8f product 0x3013 version 0x110
 Input device name: "HuiJia  USB GamePad"
```

The problem I seem to be having is Spelunky HD is looking for
    /dev/input/js2 while my controler shows up as `/dev/input/event2`.
    I've tried to link directories, but to no avail. (`/dev/input/event2` is also known as `/dev/input/js1`)

This is the output of  jstest

jstest --normal  /dev/input/event2
Driver version is 0.8.0.

`jstest is not fully compatible with your kernel.
Unable to retrieve button map! Joystick (Unknown) has 2 axes and 2 buttons.`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Steam has answered this problem.  They have an internal (to Steam) version of wine that has access to controllers. 
You are required to use the beta client of Steam for the new version of wine named Proton.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wb9RupIkhQ8
https://steamcommunity.com/games/221410/announcements/detail/1696055855739350561